# meson: how to use dependencies correctly

Tags: c++, meson-build

I have a small project I'm developing for the first time in C++.

I chose meson as my build system, and I'm pretty sure I'm missing some good practices, because:

1. My executable seems way too large (~1100 lines of code + dependencies -> 16MB)
2. My compile time takes way too long (~30 seconds)

My meson.build:

```
# builds the project and copies all relevant data files
project(
  'demo',
  'cpp',
  default_options : [
    'cpp_std=c++20',
  ],
  version: run_command('cat', '.version').stdout().strip(),
)

################
# dependencies #
################
dependencies = [
  dependency('CLI11'),
  dependency('LocalDep', modules: ['LocalDep::lib_name']), # Also used meson.get_compiler('cpp').find_library('lib_name'). Worked, but same executable size :(
  dependency('nlohmann_json'),
  dependency('spdlog'),
]

###############
# source code #
###############
sources = files()
subdir('src') # src holds another meson.build file

#########
# flags #
#########
cpp_args = ['-Wall', '-Wextra', '-Werror']
link_args = []

##############
# executable #
##############
executable(
  'demo',
  sources,
  cpp_args: cpp_args,
  link_args: link_args,
  dependencies : dependencies,
  install : true,
)
```

I call meson like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

readonly cores=$(($(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo) - 1))
readonly builddir=".build"

time {
    CXX="ccache clang++" CXX_LD="mold" meson "$builddir"
    meson compile -C $builddir -j $cores --ninja-args="-j $cores"
}
```

I recently tried to cross compile to ARM, and got a few issues that prompted to look better into my build, and now I have the following questions:

1. Is my way of calling dependencies makes sense? I know I can, for example, install spdlog on my global environment. It is probably less portable, but would that be better (faster compile time - smaller executable - faster runtime)?
2. The `dependency('LocalDep', modules: ['LocalDep::lib_name'])` is a dependency I've installed via `dpkg` - it is a library + header files that I can find under `/usr/lib` and `/usr/include` respectively. I've got the feeling that, for some reason, the library is being **statically** linked into my executable. AFAIK - this means slightly better runtime, but bigger executable + slower compile time. I prefer, for development phase, to move it into a dynamic linkage, but couldn't (0) verify my theory, (1) figure out how to change it

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The dependency , if you need all of them, are defined in the correct way.

Regarding the point 2 the lib lib_name that you look under /usr/bin I suppose is a shared one, you can verify easily looking at the extension .so, in that case it is linked as shared one .